# Duvida sobre ajax (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

to com uma duvida, tem como enviar da index para a api (usando o ajax) mais de um valor?. estou acustumado a usar o código assim.
Mas não sei como faço pra enviar o valor de 2 inputs diferentes.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php?line=' + value,
    type: 'GET',
</script>
```

Comment: Não entendi sua dúvida, tente explicá-la de forma mais clara para que possa ser ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Use `&` para separar os parâmetros:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'api.php?line=' + value + '&other=' + outro,
    type: 'GET'
});
```

Se forem muitos valores, ou valores longos, use `POST` em vez de `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Aconselho a pesquisar sobre *query strings* é que na verdade a sua limitação e que nada tem a ver com o pedido via Ajax.

Veja um artigo sobre query string na Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Não entrar em detalhes sobre a construção do URL para indicar que os parâmetros no URL são separados através do caractere "&" segundo a fórmula:
nome_do_parametro_1=valor_do_parametro_1&nome_do_parametro_2=valor_do_parametro_2&nome_do_parametro_3=valor_do_parametro_3...

Usando o seu exemplo vou acrescentar parâmetro coluna

```
<script>
$.ajax({
   url: 'api.php?line=' + value +'&coluna=' + value2,
   type: 'GET',
</script>
```